# SQLite Update not working for list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I write this code and the logic should be like when item on list view clicked an int database update to 1 and if you click again update again to 0 but its only updating to 0

```
listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView,  
        View view, 
        int groupPosition, 
        int childPosition, 
        long id) {
            int num = dbHelper.getActive(child.getTourId(),child.getSiteName());
            if (num == 1){
                Log.i("database",num+"");
                dbHelper.setDeAvtive(child.getSiteName(),child.getTourId());

            } else if (num == 0){
                Log.i("database",num+"");
                dbHelper.setActive(child.getSiteName(),child.getTourId());                   
            }
            return true;
            }
    });
}
```

and this is my DB classes

Active Class

```
 public void setActive(String name,int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ChildTour.ACTIVE,1);
    db.update(name,values,ChildTour.ACTIVE+"="+id,null);
    Log.i("database",id+" Activated");
```

deActive Class

```
public void setDeAvtive(String name,int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ChildTour.ACTIVE,0);
    db.update(name,values,ChildTour.ACTIVE+"="+id,null);
    Log.i("database",id+" DeActivated");
```

getActive class

```
 public int getActive(int tourId,String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    int activeCode = 0;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + ChildTour.ACTIVE + " FROM "
                + name + " WHERE " + ChildTour.TOUR_ID + " = " + tourId, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            activeCode= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChildTour.ACTIVE));
            Log.i("databse", "UpdateCode is: " + updateCode);

        }
        return activeCode;
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

and this my Log for clicking 5 times

```
12-24 09:32:02.091 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
12-24 09:32:02.331 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 0
12-24 09:32:02.331 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
12-24 09:32:02.571 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 0
12-24 09:32:02.571 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
12-24 09:32:02.761 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 0
12-24 09:32:02.761 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
12-24 09:32:02.991 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 0
12-24 09:32:02.991 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
12-24 09:32:03.171 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 0
12-24 09:32:03.171 5032-5032/app.mma.introsliderproject I/database: 3 Activated
```

Comment: check the return of the update() method, it returns number of rows affected

Comment: @elmorabea i check that always 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im so sorry guys im new on setActive and setDeActive Update code should be like this `db.update(name,values,ChildTour.TOUR_ID+"="+id,null);`
again im sorry

Comment: yea that was my mistake i really need to sleep @ABDevelopers